# Removing dollar signs from prices

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm building a string of amounts but need to remove the dollar signs. I have this jQuery code:

```
  buildList($('.productPriceID > .productitemcell'), 'pricelist')
```

It's returning

```
pricelist=$15.00,$19.50,$29.50
```

I need to remove the dollar signs but can't seem to figure it out. Tried using .trim but I think that removes only white space.

Sorry for the newbie question! Thanks in advance for any help!

Here's the full code:

```
function buildList(items, name) {
var values = [];
items.each(function() {
values.push(this.value || $(this).text());
});
return name + '=' + values.join(',');
}

var result = [
buildList($('.productCodeID > .productitemcell'), 'skulist'),
buildList($('.productQuantityID > .productitemcell > input'), 'quantitylist'),
buildList($('.productPriceID > .productitemcell'), 'pricelist')
];

var string = result.join('&');
```

Here is the raw code before the javascript runs

```
<span class="productPriceID">
<div class="productitemcell">$15.00</div>
<div class="productitemcell">$19.50</div>
<div class="productitemcell">$29.50</div>
</span>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with JQuery, it's just javascript in this case.

Comment: True. It's wrapped in some jquery above it. I've included more code so hopefully it makes more sense.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**EDIT:** Starting over with answer now that I have the code that is running.

Looking at your updated code, this should work:

**Example:** http://jsbin.com/ekege3/

```
var result = [
    buildList($('.productCodeID > .productitemcell'), 'skulist'),
    buildList($('.productQuantityID > .productitemcell > input'), 'quantitylist'),
    buildList($('.productPriceID > .productitemcell'), 'pricelist')
];

result[ 2 ] = result[ 2 ].replace(/\$/g, '');

var string = result.join('&');
```

---

**Side note:** You can shorten your `buildList` function a little like this:

```
function buildList(items, name) {
    return (name + '=') + items.map(function() {
        return (this.value || $(this).text());
    }).get().join(',');
}
```

---

**Original answer:**

<s>If you have a string, just use `.replace()`.</s>

```
var str = "pricelist=$15.00,$19.50,$29.50";

str = str.replace(/\$/g, '');
```

Or are you saying that you have a variable `pricelist` containing an Array? If so, do this:

```
var pricelist = ["$15.00","$19.50","$29.50"];

for( var i = 0, len = pricelist.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    pricelist[ i ] = pricelist[ i ].replace('$', '');
}
```

---

**EDIT:** It sounds as though the `buildList` method returns an Array.

One way to check would be to do this:

```
alert( Object.prototype.toString.call( result[2] ) );
```

And see what it gives you.

Anyway, assuming it's an Array, here's the updated version of the second example.

```
var result = [
    buildList($('.productCodeID > .productitemcell'), 'skulist'),
    buildList($('.productQuantityID > .productitemcell > input'), 'quantitylist'),
    buildList($('.productPriceID > .productitemcell'), 'pricelist')
];

// verify the data type
alert( Object.prototype.toString.call( result[ 2 ] ) );

// loop over result[ 2 ], replacing the $ with ''
for( var i = 0, len = result[ 2 ].length; i < len; i++ ) {
    result[ 2 ][ i ] = result[ 2 ][ i ].replace('$', '');
}

var string = result.join('&');
```

Comment: I've updated the code above. Basically, the price list is being built from a list of prices. I need to remove the dollar signs at some point in the process. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @mmsa - If you can, modify the markup so that you're not getting the `$` in the first place. Otherwise, it seems like you're saying that `buildList` returns a string, so my first example should work. If you want to do it before you do the `join()`, then just use my first example, but replace `str` with `result[ 2 ]` as in `result[ 2 ] = result[ 2 ].replace(/\$/g, '')`.

Comment: First, thanks for your help! It's not working for some reason. In your example above, your variable str is a fixed value. Those dollar figures will change for each user. It's pulled from a shopping card. I put the code it but it's generating an error on .replace for some reason.

Comment: @patrick dw - One other thought, is there an easy way to remove it from the original numbers? I've pasted the original code above. This is what renders from the CMS before the javascript runs. I wish I had control over the dollar signs but I don't. Thanks Again!

Comment: @mmsa - The trouble is that I don't know what type of data the `buildList` returns. Now I'm guessing it is an Array, which means you would use the second example. It will be easier to update it in my answer. Give me just a minute. And regarding changing the markup, you might as well just do it like you are since it sounds like you can't change it from the server.

Comment: @patrick dw - I've updated my code with then entire script above. I tried putting in the code as you've noted. I get the alert with [object String]. Does that help. Dollar signs are still there.

Comment: @mmsa - Yes, knowing it is a String does help, so we're back to the first version. It should work if this is your actual code. I'll update my answer now that I know we're dealing with a String. Just a minute.

Comment: @patrick dw - You're not going to believe this but it's still not working! The final code still shows dollar signs. Any ideas??

Comment: @mmsa - What do you mean by final result? How are you testing the result? Did you try the example I linked to? Are you doing anything differently?

Comment: @mmsa - Did you get this figured out? If it's not removing the `$`, then we're missing something somewhere.

Comment: No I didn't. Just got back to the computer. I'm testing by placing the code after the html which contains the lists. When the page renders, the $ is still there. Let me know if you have other suggestions.

Comment: @patrick dw - I just checked the page again and it looks like the code is working. I wonder if I was dealing with a caching issue. Sorry for the back and forth. Thanks a ton for the help!

Comment: @mmsa - Not a problem. Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 12):

```
var price = $("div").text().replace("$", "");
```