# how to ignore specific character on a text element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the text element from a `div` that has this content: `<div class="balance"...>$500.48</div>`

What I need is to get the `500.48` as a value, not a as string.

I have used `alert($(".balance").text())` to check if it is returning the content and it does, but I need it to be a number. I know that if I store the string on a variable and do this:

```
x =  $(".balance").text() ;
x = +x;
```

It'll convert the string into a number, so I tried to ignore the `$` but I had no success.
What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209130/removing-dollar-signs-from-prices

Comment: Declaring variable in javascript  like `var somename;` not only `var`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var val = parseFloat($(".balance").text().replace('$',''));
```

---

[.parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

Answer (score 1):

**Handles Any Currency Symbol**

The following uses a regular expression so your code will work with any currency.

```
var balanceValueElementValue1 = parseFloat($('.balance').text().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,''));
```

**Quick Markup Suggestion**

You might want to house your value inside a span element and add an identifier to the value element so you can target it more consistently and accurately.

```
<div class="balance">
    <span id="balance-value-1">$500.48</span>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
var balanceValueElementValue1 = parseFloat($('#balance-value-1').text().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,''));
```

**JavaScript**

```
var balanceValueElement = document.getElementById("balance-value-1");
var balanceValueElementInnerText = balanceValueElement.innerText;
var balanceValueElementValue1 = parseFloat(balanceValueElementInnerText.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,''));
```