# How to strip the dollar sign from an array and keep only numbers? js

Tags: javascript, html

with the code below I am trying to get elements by class name in javascript and I am storing them in an array.

this is the output I get : "I get this output the initial prices array $ 30.00,$ 20.00,$ 40.00"

My question is how can I strip the $ sign from the array and store only the numbers? like so 
initialprices = [20, 30, 40]?

```js
var initialprices = document.getElementsByClassName("price");
var initialprice = [];
flag = false;
//for every element in initialprices array get their value from innerhtml
for (var i = 0; i < initialprices.length; i++) {
  initialprice.push(initialprices[i].innerHTML);
  console.log("the initial prices array " + initialprice);
}
```

```html
<p class ="price">$ 30.00</p>
<p class ="price">$ 20.00</p>
<p class ="price">$ 40.00</p>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing dollar signs from prices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209130/removing-dollar-signs-from-prices)

Comment: If it's under your control; it's much better to store them without the Dollar sign and add it when you display them to a human.

Comment: Initialprice is declared as an empty array to store the values of intitialpriceS array elements.

Answer (score 3):

Use `replace` and then convert to number with the unary plus.
The `Array.from` function can map the DOM elements to those numbers:

```js
var initialprices = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".price"),
                               price => +price.textContent.replace("$", ""));
console.log(initialprices);
```

```html
<p class ="price">$ 30.00</p>
<p class ="price">$ 20.00</p>
<p class ="price">$ 40.00</p>
```

Comment: @MantasStanionis Please mark this as the correct answer if it helped you solve your issue. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Strip the unwanted characters and parse as a number before adding to your array:

```js
var initialprices = document.getElementsByClassName("price");
var initialpriceArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < initialprices.length; i++) {
  initialpriceArray.push(parseFloat(initialprices[i].innerHTML.replace(/\$\s/g, '')));
}
console.log("initialpriceArray", initialpriceArray);
```

```html
<p class="price">$ 30.00</p>
<p class="price">$ 20.00</p>
<p class="price">$ 40.00</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the prices converted to numbers:

```
var initialprices = document.getElementsByClassName("price");

flag = false;
//for every element in initialprices array get their value from innerhtml
for (var i = 0; i < initialprices.length; i++) {
  initialprice.push(
    parseFloat(initialprices[i].innerHTML.replace("$", ""))
  );
  console.log("the initial prices array " + initialprice);
}
```